# service restart with buildozer cant find class?

Tags: python, android, service, kivy, buildozer

i have tried many solutions and followed many guides but i cant get it to work i have a minimal code example here.

this is my main.py:

```
import kivy
import platform
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
import jnius
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition



class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() #(transition=FadeTransition())
        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

    def change(self, *args):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.fscreen.ids.lb.text = str(self.cnt) + ' hello '
        print(str(self.cnt) + ' hello ')
    def label_update(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change, 1)

    def on_start(self):
        from kivy import platform
        if platform == "android":
            self.start_service()
        Process(target=self.label_update).start()

    @staticmethod
    def start_service():
        from jnius import autoclass
        service = autoclass("org.pck.ser.Serviceser")
        mActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity").mActivity
        service.start(mActivity, "")
        return service

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()                                       
    theapp.run()
```

this is a my kv file:

```
<fscreen>
    Label:
        id:lb
        size: root.width*0.1, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.45,root.height*0.3
```

and this is my service.py same folder as main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from jnius import autoclass

PythonService = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonService')
PythonService.mService.setAutoRestartService(True)

while True:
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
```

this is the buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ser

# (str) Package name
package.name = ser

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.pck

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.2,numpy,pillow,kivy_garden.mapview,requests,charset_normalizer,chardet,idna, urllib3,certifi,plyer==2.0.0,sqlite3,pickle-mixin,kivygradient,jnius,android
services = ser:service.py
```

and i have this output from buildozer android debug deploy run logcat i have cleaned modified versions and did a lot of things but same thing i dont know what i am missing

```
04-16 02:42:04.993 18517 18610 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-16 02:42:04.994 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 57, in <module>
04-16 02:42:04.994 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/ser/armeabi-v7a/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
04-16 02:42:04.995 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/ser/armeabi-v7a/kivy/app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
04-16 02:42:04.995 18517 18610 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
04-16 02:42:04.995 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 44, in on_start
04-16 02:42:04.996 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 50, in start_service
04-16 02:42:04.996 18517 18610 I python  :    File "/home/odr/Desktop/dev/MobileApps/foreground_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/ser/armeabi-v7a/jnius/reflect.py", line 229, in autoclass
04-16 02:42:04.996 18517 18610 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 26, in jnius.jnius.find_javaclass
04-16 02:42:04.997 18517 18610 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
04-16 02:42:04.997 18517 18610 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Didn't find class "org.pck.ser.Serviceser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.pck.ser-KtQcSSOANf-UBQoqXEY3dA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.pck.ser-KtQcSSOANf-UBQoqXEY3dA==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.pck.ser-KtQcSSOANf-UBQoqXEY3dA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
04-16 02:42:04.997 18517 18610 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some lines and cleaned my buildozer:

this is the complete working version of my buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ser

# (str) Package name
package.name = ser

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.pck

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,db,ttf,wav

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = cache/*.png,fonts/cello-sans/*.ttf,fonts/fondation/*.ttf

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
#requirements = python3,Kivy-Garden==0.1.1,futures==2.1.6,requests==1.2.3,certifi,urllib3,chardet,idna
#requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.2,numpy,pillow,kivy_garden.mapview,requests,charset_normalizer,chardet,idna, urllib3,certifi,plyer==2.0.0,sqlite3,pickle-mixin,kivygradient,jnius,android
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.2,numpy,pillow,kivy_garden.mapview,requests,charset_normalizer,chardet,idna, urllib3,certifi,plyer==2.0.0,sqlite3,pickle-mixin,kivygradient,android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements = kivy.garden.mapview

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
services = Worker:service.py

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, FOREGROUND_SERVICE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

this is main.py:

```
import kivy
import platform
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from jnius import autoclass
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
import jnius
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition



class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() #(transition=FadeTransition())
        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

    def change(self, *args):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.fscreen.ids.lb.text = str(self.cnt) + ' hello '
        print(str(self.cnt) + ' hello ')
    def label_update(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change, 1)

    def on_start(self):
        from kivy import platform

        if platform == "android":

            self.start_service()
            print('service started')
        Process(target=self.label_update).start()

    #@staticmethod
    def start_service(self):
        from android import mActivity
        context =  mActivity.getApplicationContext()
        SERVICE_NAME = str(context.getPackageName()) + '.Service' + 'Worker'
        service = autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
        print(SERVICE_NAME)
        service.start(mActivity,'')
        return service
        print('returned service')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()                                       
    theapp.run()
```

and this service.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from jnius import autoclass
import time


PythonService = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonService')
PythonService.mService.setAutoRestartService(True)

while True:
    print('this is my service and its running')
    time.sleep(1)
```

and this is the cat after `adb logcat -s Worker`:

```
04-16 03:38:08.882 26990 27006 I Worker  : this is my service and its running
04-16 03:38:09.884 26990 27006 I Worker  : this is my service and its running
```